# Passing Variables into PHP Function Scope

Tags: php

Is there a way to pass a variable into a function scope in PHP similar to Javascript? Here's what I understand thus far:

```
// Simple Function
$hello_world = function(){
    echo 'Hello World 1';
};
$hello_world();

// Using Global Variable
$text = 'Hello World 2';
$hello_world = function(){
    // Need to Add Global
    global $text;
    // Adding Text
    echo $text;
};
$hello_world();


// Dynamically Created Functions
$function_list = [];
// Function to Create Dynamic Function
function create_dynamic_function($function_name,$response_text){
    global $function_list;
    $function_list[$function_name] = function(){
        echo $response_text;    // Want to Echo the Input $response_text, but it cannot find it
    };
}

create_dynamic_function('Hello','Hello World 3');
$function_list['Hello'](); // Doesn't Work
```

I would like to pass the response text into the newly generated function without have to check what is response_text. it could be a string, int, boolean, object etc

Comment: `function() use($response_text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$response_text` isn't in scope inside the anonymous function that you're creating:

```
function create_dynamic_function($function_name,$response_text){
    global $function_list;
    $function_list[$function_name] = function() use ($response_text) {
        echo $response_text;    // Want to Echo the Input $response_text, but it cannot find it
    };
}
```

For reference, arguments passed to an anonymous function are values applied when that function is executed; arguments passed via `use` are values applied when the function is defined.

Comment: Thank a lot :). I'm just a newbie PHP coder, and most of my coding knowledge is from Javascript. I figure PHP is similar to Javascript enough. I will mark this as accepted answer when I am able.